# How can I make the pillars of a bridge automatically touch the ground?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am making a bridge in Geometry Nodes and I want to create a system in which the bottom of the pillars automatically touch the ground. This way they each would have a broader part near the ground and then become more narrow towards the middle.

I'm guessing that the Raycast Node could be a part of the solution? Maybe together with the selection of the bottom 2 vertices of the curve of the pillar? I'm not able to make it work.

Screenshots and blender file below for clarification:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update for 3 parts:

node tree:

[image]

Be aware that i also change the origin/pivot points of the 3 parts to make it work.

result:

[image]

[image]

---

you could do it like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

But...remember:

It is raycasting here "just" from that one curve of the pillars downwards so it might be a bit inaccurate because the pillar foot it pretty wide, so the foot could be sometimes "in the air" or "deep in the earth".
I had to adjust the origin of the pillar so that i could calculate it much easier.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thank you for that! That looks already better. (but I'm not able to reproduce your result. What do you do with the named attribute?) The disadvantage of this system is that the pillars geometry gets quite distorted with more complex models. Would it be possible to only influence the bottom vertices of the pillars as I explain in this image? [Link to image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iy533gzn808s5vt/Screenshot%202022-11-02%20131014.png?dl=0/)

Comment: maybe a better solution would be to have 3 parts. 1 top part which always is the same and is fixed to the street. Same with one bottom part, fixed to landscape. And one "flexible" middle part which is just straight so you can scale it on z without it looking like sh*t ;)

Comment: named attributes just "store" values for later use. That's all. It's like variables in programming languages.

Comment: The solution with the 3 parts would actually be great. It would allow me to swap out the parts easily too, for some variation. Thanks for that idea! :-) 
I tried to make it work, following your example, but I'm afraid I was not able to. I changed the Blender file in my original question and I made a pillar with 3 parts in that one.
Could you maybe have a look as to what I did wrong? I have no clue. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! That's awesome :D It's quite satisfying to move the road around with the pillars automatically adapting to the landscape. Is there a way I can buy you a coffee? :-)

Comment: I see that you use both a **'store named attribute'** node for the top pillar part and a **'named attribute'** node for the middle pillar part. I have been trying to figure out where these attributes refer to and I would love to understand it. Where do these refer to please?

Comment: @PieterLeon: yes you can buy me a coffee, just write me an email, my email is in my profile here. If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thanks. I don't know whether you are familiar with programming languages but basically the store named attribute saves a value to a variable with the name you gave it (just a value input). The "named attribute" just reads that variable (just a value output). I am saving the position of the points to "reuse" the values as source position for the raycast node.

Comment: if you are not a programmer: The "store named attribute" saves the value (in this case: the position) of the points of the street curve (which are the positions of the top pillar objects). The "named attribute" just reads that values and then you can use them as i used it to use it as source position for the raycast node. So these are the points from which i raycast in the direction (0,0,-1) , so i raycast downwards from the top pillar objects. By this i get a "hit point" of that raycast with the landscape and i got the point, where the bottom part should be.

Comment: Hi @Chris
Thank you for the explanation. I am not a programmer and I have been trying to learn Geometry Nodes for the past couple of months. I think what confuses me a bit is that you gave the attribute in the **"store named attribute node'** a different name ( namely: '*top*') as compared to the name you refer to in the **'named attribute node'** ('*pos*').

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind: would there be a possibility to avoid pillars hitting the road underneath, when the same road (curve) goes on top of itself in a loop, as illustrated in this image? [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sylbdeij8i2nbxq/Screenshot%202022-11-05%20102924.png?dl=0/)

Comment: Hi Pieter, pls open a new question for this because it is "another" question. You can open as many questions as you like. Answers in comment won't be found by anyone because Blender SE doesn't search in comments so other people with the same question cannot find it. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, that's nice. I didn't know that and I will do that. Thanks for the information.