# How can the pillars of a looped bridge be stopped of touching the road underneath?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, geometry

In a previous question ([Link to Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278293/how-can-i-make-the-pillars-of-a-bridge-automatically-touch-the-ground/278295?noredirect=1#comment478374_278295)) I asked about letting the pillars of a bridge automatically touch the ground. This was solved by @Chris

Now I am wondering if there is a way to avoid that the pillars hit the road underneath, when the same road (curve) goes on top of itself in a loop, as illustrated in the image below?

The Blender file is also in attachment below.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my proposal:

I made another raycast to the street and deleted the instances according to hit or not:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully! :D Thank you very much Chris. This is awesome. I could make some kind of roller-coaster with this system. :-)

Comment: Glad i could help. You are one of the "seldom" people here who write good questions, provide enough informations (and not too much) and (for me) the best: you provide the blend file so that we can ourselves try whether our solution works. I know there are a lot of "theoretical" people here who love to answer without blend file, the problem is just: they can never be 100% sure that their provided solution works because it is almost always the case that is a certain amount of guessing and therefore their answer might be a waste of time or worse: just wrong

Comment: I didn't know that. That's nice to hear, thanks. I'm very thankful for the help.